# Where is Maharshal's commentary on birkat hamazon printed?

Tags: prayer-book, bentching

I read in an [EJ article](https://www.encyclopedia.com/religion/encyclopedias-almanacs-transcripts-and-maps/luria-solomon-ben-jehiel) by Israel Ta-Shma on Maharshal: "Luria wrote a commentary to the Grace after Meals (Venice, 1603; Jerusalem, 1982)." So I understand that Maharshal wrote a commentary on birkat hamazon, and it's been published, but under what title or with what other work, I've not found. Does anyone know if/where I can find it published?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that this commentary might not exist at all, and might be a mis-cataloguing that propogated to encyclopedia articles. In particular:

- There's a Vienna 1603 printing of a commentary on birkat hamazon by R. Natan Shapira, and at the back is a commentary on zemirot by Maharshal. See [here](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990010720890205171/NLI).
- There's a Jerusalem 1982 print of Maharshal's zemirot commentary. See [here](https://www.nli.org.il/he/books/NNL_ALEPH990021740250205171/NLI).

It seems likely that the Vienna 1603 print was misattributed to Maharshal in its entirety (he *is* the more famous of the two), and then somehow the mistaken metadata propogated to the 1982 edition. I corresponded with someone who worked on a research project on R. Natan Shapira, and he recalled that indeed "this attribution is a bit of a cataloging error". My further searching in the NLI database turned up no other hits, and so I present this as the currently most likely explanation.